# Full copy small List to Container List, not only reference

Tags: c#, list, object, reference

I was hoping the new keyword, would not only create a new object, but also with unique memory references. If I do this, and after Clear the "tinyList", the bigList will also be cleared.

```
bigList.Add(new bigListObject(tinyList));
```

bigList is a List and Construcotr looks like

```
public Foo(List<SmallClass> in)
    {
        _test = new List<SmallClass>();
        _test = in;
    }
```

This works, but how can I clear the tinyList, fill it, and continue adding to bigList?
The whole idea is to have a big list and one small for adding.. Now I have two lists from two different classes, almost the same.
Thanks

Comment: Which List class are you using?  Is it [this one?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Comment: You should clone/copy somehow the objects in the source list.

Comment: @RobertHarvey List<myBigClass> bigList. And myBigClass has a constructor that looks like this: public Foo(List<smallClass> in)
        {
            _test = new List<SmallClass>();
            _test = in;
        }

Comment: @I4V Yes, but was hoping I didn't need to use ICloneable or something

Comment: But you create a new list in `_test` and then discard it with `_test = in`.

Comment: @ja72 I know, messed up. I got the answear from below. It's supposed to be: _test = new List<SmallClass>(in);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy the *references* to a new list:

```
public Foo(List<SmallClass> in)
{
    _test = new List<SmallClass>(in);
}
```

now `_test` and `in` point to two different lists, so removing an object from one list does not affect the other.

However, they are the same *references*.  So editing one of the `SmallClass` instances in list `in` will affect the corresponding instance in list `_test` because the references point to the same instances.

If you need copies of the `SmallClass` instances then you'll need to implement a copy method (or use [`object.MemberwiseClone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx))

Comment: Ah, So that's what the List constructor can be used as! Nice one! :)

Comment: The objects will not be edited, only the list of SmallClass (tinyList) will be Cleared()